# Is there a transitive set which is not inductive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a transitive set which is not inductive? Appreciate any advice , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{\varnothing\}$ is not inductive. Can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

$\varnothing$ is not inductive.  Can you see why?

Comment: (Sorry, Asaf.  I couldn't resist.)

Comment: Assuming the pattern continues, this implies that $-1$ is not inductive... Can you see why? ;) (Sorry Trevor, I couldn't resist)